# Tile script (Mapnik) with OpenLayers - Problem with projection (900913)

Tags: python, coordinate-system, mapnik

I use Mapnik python bindings in a geodjango application to render tiles in openlayers with datasource stored in postGIS in 900913 projection. The feature seems to be rendered correctly in the spherical mercator projection, but at a very high zoomLevel in the very left corner of the world map so the features seems really tiny.

*EDIT: After several test the problem seems to be in the first lines of the script where minLong, minLat, maxLong, and maxLat are defined. Someone has a similar tiling script in 900913?*

[image]

This is weird because the bounds of the features are:

> -8879435.28405854, 5620161.13498339, -6337967.06663213, 8998594.89464899

but they are rendered around this position in the map:

> lat: -19955850.825909 lon: -19952809.28254

There is the script

```
MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL = 20
TILE_WIDTH = 256
TILE_HEIGHT = 256

dbSettings = settings.DATABASES['default']

def tile(request, version, shapefile_id, zoom, x, y):

    try:
        if version != "1.0":
            raise Http404
        try:
            shapefile = Shapefile.objects.get(id=shapefile_id, created_by=request.user)
        except Shapefile.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        zoom = int(zoom)
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        if zoom < 0 or zoom > MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL:
            raise Http404
        xExtent = _unitsPerPixel(zoom) * TILE_WIDTH
        yExtent = _unitsPerPixel(zoom) * TILE_HEIGHT
        minLong = x * xExtent - 200037508.34
        minLat = y * yExtent - 200037508.34
        maxLong = minLong + xExtent
        maxLat = minLat + yExtent

        #create de mapnik.map object
        map = mapnik.Map(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +units=m +k=1.0 +nadgrids=@null +no_defs")
        map.background = mapnik.Color("#7391ad")

        #defining the feature layer
        geometryField = utils.calcGeometryField(shapefile.geom_type)
        query = '(select ' + geometryField + ', id from "shapefile_feature" where' + ' shapefile_id=' + str(shapefile.id) + ') as geom'

        datasource = mapnik.PostGIS(user=dbSettings['USER'],
                        password=dbSettings['PASSWORD'],
                        dbname=dbSettings['NAME'],
                        table=query,
                        srid=900913,
                        geometry_field=geometryField,
                        geometry_table='"shapefile_feature"',
                        simplify_geometries=True)

        featureLayer = mapnik.Layer("featureLayer")
        featureLayer.srs = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over"
        featureLayer.datasource = datasource
        featureLayer.styles.append("featureLayerStyle")

        #defining the feature layer styles
        rule = mapnik.Rule()
        if shapefile.geom_type in ["Point", "MultiPoint"]:
            rule.symbols.append(mapnik.PointSymbolizer())
        elif shapefile.geom_type in ["LineString", "MultiLineString"]:
            rule.symbols.append(mapnik.LineSymbolizer(mapnik.Color("#000000"), 0.5))
        elif shapefile.geom_type in ["Polygon", "MultiPolygon"]:
            rule.symbols.append(mapnik.PolygonSymbolizer(mapnik.Color("#f7edee")))
            rule.symbols.append(mapnik.LineSymbolizer(mapnik.Color("#000000"), 0.5))
        style = mapnik.Style()
        style.rules.append(rule)

        #add new feature to the map
        map.append_style("featureLayerStyle", style)
        map.layers.append(featureLayer)
        map.srs = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +units=m +k=1.0 +nadgrids=@null +no_defs"
        #rendering the map tile
        map.zoom_to_box(mapnik.Box2d(minLong, minLat, maxLong, maxLat))
        image = mapnik.Image(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT)
        mapnik.render(map, image)
        imageData = image.tostring('png')
        return HttpResponse(imageData, image)

    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return HttpResponse("")

def _unitsPerPixel(zoomLevel):
    return 400075016.68 / math.pow(2, zoomLevel)
```

In openlayers.html

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',
          {maxResolution: 156543.0399,
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
            units: 'm',
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34),
            numZoomLevels: 21});
tiledLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS('TMS',
                "{{ tmsURL }}",
                {serviceVersion: "1.0",
                layername: "{{ shapefile.id }}",
                type: 'png',
                projection: map.projection});
map.addLayer(tiledLayer);
```

What am I missging? why the features are not rendered at their normal sizes and positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can spot two things:

1. Change every instance of `EPSG:900913` to `EPSG:3857` -- EPSG:900913 (Or EPSG:GOOGLE if you squint hard enough) never existed in the EPSG database. It's a long story, but EPSG:3857 is the correct code.
2. It looks like you have one too many zeroes when you initialize your `minLat` and `minLong` variables. Compare it to your `new OpenLayers.Bounds` in the HTML.

Comment: Now that Mintx has pointed the coordinate value problem out (I can see it now!), the 2*20million value in def _unitsPerPixel(zoomLevel) also has one too many zeroes.

Comment: Good catch! That was not an easy one to find. Thank you!

Comment: @mkennedy btw, great to meet you at APSG! :)

Answer (score 1):

Many different tools implement conversions between tile z/x/y and bounding boxes for a given projection. This problem is not specific to Mapnik at all. Why not use a library like TileStache, Invar, or MapProxy?

Comment: I use Mapnik in GeoDjango, im not sure about adding another server like TileStache. I would like to have its features but dont know if its good to bind it inside geodjango.

Comment: Anyway im not using Mapnik xml and tilestache seems not to support mapnik.Map object directly

Comment: creating mapnik xml from a python mapnik.Map object is easy: https://gist.github.com/springmeyer/5637596